# Does not work isset post in dynamically created submit

Tags: javascript, php

I have code in PHP file:

```
<form id="form_id" action="" method="post">
<?php if (isset($_POST["123"])) {echo "BUTTON WORKS";}?>
</form>
<script src="file.js"></script>
```

And I have code in JS file:

```
let testButton = document.createElement("submit");
testButton.innerHTML = "Click it";
document.getElementById ("form_id").appendChild(testButton);
testButton.name = "123";
```

php code does not work. Why?

Comment: I've never seen a `<submit>` element before, is there such a thing?  (Maybe some legacy vestige I've just never encountered?)  Did you mean to use a `<button>` element?  An `<input>` with a `type` of `"submit"`?

Comment: You probably want to create an element "input" with type="submit"

Comment: @Val  if you found my answer useful, then would be great to accept it...

Answer (score 2):

Create a `button` element not `submit` like this one

```
 let testButton = document.createElement("button"); /*HERE*/
testButton.innerHTML = "Click it";
document.getElementById ("form_id").appendChild(testButton);
testButton.name = "123";
```